# UISearchBar background image showing black color on edges

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar

I am trying to apply background image on UISearchBar. It is successfully applied but balck color is shown on the four edges of search bar.
[image: SearchBar]

Here is the code I am using:

```
[_dashboardSearch setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-bar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_dashboardSearch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_dashboardSearch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_icon.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: You can try - self.mySearchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: @mKane that's not working..

Comment: Try [self.mySearchBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: This too not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved. I was setting the black color to UITexfield background inside UISearchBar. Following line of code was written by mistake:

```
[(UITextField *)subSubView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```